# Reporting or combining multiple t-test results

Tags: t-test, p-value, meta-analysis

I am analyzing an anomaly event of daily stock returns. For many different stocks (>1000), I do some analysis to identify a day where I observe this anomaly.

To evaluate the effect of this anomaly, I am comparing the distribution of returns during a fixed period (e.g. one year) before and after the event date. For example, I calculate t-statistic and p-value with a paired t-test, under the null hypothesis that the mean of returns (or other company metrics) will be equal before and after. I repeat this for every event, of which I have a few thousand.

I am looking for a concise way of reporting these test results, and to interpret them. My current approach is to report 1 percent and 5 percent quantiles of calculated p-values to show what proportion of events generates a significant change. Furthermore, I report min/max and quartiles of observed t-statistics to illuminate the spread.

a.) Is this an appropriate approach?

b.) Are there any implications that I am not considering right now?

c.) Is there a better way? For example, I found a suggestion to t-test whether the distribution of t-statistics matches the expectation, but I am not certain this makes sense.

Thanks in advance!

NB: I also run Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests on before and after returns to see if the distribution of returns changes. Here I am interested in the effect of the mean of distributions.